Increment Identifier in MySQL
I am working on a table that will ultimately keep track of pallets related to specific jobs, the machine that created the pallet, the last machine to interact with the pallet, and whether the pallet is available to be modified. The following fields describe this:
JobNum (varchar), PalletNum (int), CreatingMachine (int), LastUsedMachine (int), Locked (bit)
The JobNum is the ID for the specific job, and the PalletNum starts with 1 for all jobs and should increment for each new pallet assigned to a particular job, regardless of the machine that creates it. The AUTO_INCREMENT for MySQL doesn't handle this type of incrementing, and there's the possibility of two (or more) machines attempting to claim the same pallet number on a particular job.
What method(s) are there for properly handling this kind of incrementing?
One method I've seen online involves creating a transaction, selecting the last used PalletNum for the specific JobNum using 'SELECT ... FOR UPDATE', and inserting that way before committing the transaction. However, I haven't ever used transactions and I'm unsure how they work. If other queries related to the record simply wait their turn, this doesn't seem like it would be a bad option, but if the queries fail when locked, that wouldn't be ideal.
I've also seen options using a trigger before inserting, but I've used triggers even less and understand them about the same!
Edit: The answer at Some sort of “different auto-increment indexes” per a primary key values was recommended as a duplicate question, but the answer doesn't indicate how to use either solve to this problem (getting an exclusive table lock, or manage the rolling ID outside the transaction scope).
Locking the table seems to be the most straight forward, but, as the answer mentions, runs the risk of throughput issues (though it's unlikely in my intended implementation, it's always a possibility). What other issues might arise from this?
The other option was managing the rolling ID outside the transaction scope, but the source to how that works is a broken link now.

By default, queries automatically wait for the lock to be released. The transaction method you describe is exactly how you're supposed to do this.

You could research how to do an exclusive table lock in mysql. The answer to the linked duplicate questuon gives you the theoretical background necessary for you to implement your own solution.
